# Laptop quit charging, needs new charger but which one?

Tags: laptop, hp-pavilion, voltage, charger

I have an HP Pavilion g6-2211nr I got it about 2 years ago. This last couple of months i havent been able to use it because It stopped charging. For a while It would if i held the cable a certain way but if i bumped it in the slightest it would stop charging. then it died and it wouldn't turn back on. I consulted hhgregg with the warranty and they shipped me a new battery. it turns on now and it works but the charger wont charge it at all. The charger is not covered in the warranty so i need to buy a new one. this happened earlier in the year while i still had my warranty with HP and they fixed it and replaced the charger and battery then too. That was about 4 months after I bought the laptop. But now my question is what charger is safe with it? the one i have now is (65w  19.5v  3.33a) I've looked online for a new one and the ones compatible with my laptop are (65w  18.5v and it varies with the amps) Is it okay to use those ones even though its lower? I did find one however that is 19.5v but Could they have given me the wrong charger and maybe thats why it stopped charging the second time? I need a charger soon but i dont want to get the wrong one and mess up my laptop further. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I doubt the issue is the charger. It's much more likely that the issue is the connector on the laptop that the charger plugs into has cracked off the board.

Comment: In general, most HP consumer and enterprise laptops use a similar smart ~19v  power supply, with identical plugs, and various amperage/wattage ratings of 65, 90, and 120 watts. Any of the will work but it's recommend to nor go below your computers recommended wattage rating even though it may work. In supporting hundreds of HP laptops I have found the power supply cord on the PC end to be a noticeable weak point in HPs, so a quality replacement is in order. Quality doesn't necessarily mean expensive, we use ones from Amazon that are about $15 and work well.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases for laptops these days, you can use a charger that has a higher Wattage that what your Laptop needs to charge - Most chargers indicate that they can pull a "Maximum" of "X" Watts, and the laptop will only draw the power that is needed - However, if you try to use a lower wattage charger, you could potentially damage the charger, laptop, or both.

As long as the polarity is the same on the chargers (your old one and the new one), and the AC Adapter fits, you shouldn't have a problem.

Another good bet would be to contact HP Support to see if you can purchase a verified charger for your laptop, or even see if there are any certified chargers online for your specific model.

Comment: Matching the voltage is pretty important.

Comment: @David Schwartz - Matching voltage is important, but if you are within 5% you should be OK.  The part about wattage is spot on.

Comment: @davidgo I agree that if the voltage of the power supply is within 5% of what the laptop says that it requires, you should be okay. And I agree that as long as the power supply's wattage is equal to or greater than that specified on the laptop (or its voltage times its specified current) you should be fine.